# Questions about TCP packets

Tags: ip, tcp, protocol-theory, layer4, transport-protocol

I am currently in college learning about networks, and I just wanted to make sure that I understood part of the TCP correctly.

The question is "What does TCP use to reassemble packets in the correct order?"

Is it IPv4 or IPv6? I guess I am confused about the two.

Comment: It doesn't matter if IPv4 or IPv6.  Both are network layer protocols and TCP is a transport layer protocol.

Comment: Ah I Understand now. The answer would then just be Internet Protocol

Comment: No, that's incorrect.  TCP has it's own feature to reassemble data that makes IPv4 or IPv6 irrelevant.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

TCP uses segments, but IP uses packets.

TCP will get a stream of data from the application, and it segments the data, passing the segments to IP (either IPv4 or IPv6). IP encapsulates the TCP segments into packets. IP may need to fragment the packets (IPv4 can fragment along the path, but IPv6 cannot), and IP in the destination host will reassemble the packet fragments, passing the original segment up to TCP in the destination host.

TCP will have no idea that packets were fragmented and reassembled.

Comment: If this answered your question, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: It's worth adding that after the any fragmentation/de-fragmentation, TCP reassembles the segments in the right order according to the **sequence number field in the TCP header**